# DateTime.ToString FormatException error

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to do a timer and print the value in a label. I do:

```
label1.Text = (DateTime.Now - startDate).ToString("HH:mm:ss");
```

But I receive a `FormatException` error. What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Subtracting `DateTime` from `DateTime` doen't result in `DateTime` but in `TimeSpan`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime.Now - startDate` returns a `TimeSpan` not a `DateTime`.

You need to escape colons with backslash and use lowercase `hh` in [`TimeSpan.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now - startDate;
label1.Text = diff.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
```

But note that the hour will never exceed 23 hours, the maximum value is `23:59:59`. If you want to show also the days you have to use a format like `"dd\\:hh\\:mm\\:ss"`.

Comment: It works good now. I though a DataTime was returned and not a TimeSpan

Answer (score 0):

```
label1.Text = DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(startDate.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate.Text,"hh\\:mm\\:ss"));
```